# Customize Rendered File markup?

Tags: views, theming, media

Wondering how i can control the markup returned for a Rendered file view mode?

This is within a view, i have a field which is a media file image. I set it to use the Rendered File formatter and provide a view mode i created. But i don't see where i can customize the view mode markup.

```
<div id="file-28" class="file file-image file-image-jpeg contextual-links-region">

    <h2 class="element-invisible"><a href="/file/msvujpg" class="views-ajax-processed-processed">msvu.jpg</a></h2>


<div class="content">
  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/sites/default/files/styles/featured_university/public/msvu.jpg?itok=8s4993Zo" width="352" height="240" alt="">  </div>


</div>
```

The only markup I want returned is

```
 <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/sites/default/files/styles/featured_university/public/msvu.jpg?itok=8s4993Zo" width="352" height="240" alt="">
```

I want to get rid of the div's and the whole h2 element.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variation of file_entity.tpl.php from the File Entity module using the following pattern.

```
file__{file type}__{view mode}.tpl.php
```

e.g.

```
file__image__teaser.tpl.php
```