# How to remove markup from file field

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have added a file field in views and when displaying it has some markup like this

```
 <div id="file-218" class="file file-image file-image-jpeg 
contextual-links-region">
<a href="#">

    </a>
       <h2 class="element-invisible">
  <a href="#"></a>
 <a href="/mdm.dev/file/218">6783c11f-0b05-49e3-a494-ca68d2e6c23b-2060x1366.jpeg</a></h2>
 <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
<a class="contextual-links-trigger contextual-links-trigger-active" href="#">
Configure</a>
 <ul class="contextual-links">
 <li class="file-edit first">
  <a href="/mdm.dev/file/218/edit?destination=gallery-page">Edit</a> </li>
  <li class="file-delete last">
 <a href="/mdm.dev/file/218/delete?    destination=gallery-page">Delete</a></li>
 </ul></div>

<div class="content">
<img typeof="foaf:Image" 
src="http://10.200.1.10/mdm.dev/sites/default/files/
  styles/w206xh154/public/6783c11f-0b05-49e3-a494-ca68d2e6c23b-2060x1366.jpeg?itok=bk_SdoJ3" alt=""> 
</div>


 </div>
```

While all I need is

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://10.200.1.10/mdm.dev/sites/default/files/
  styles/w206xh154/public/6783c11f-0b05-49e3-a494-ca68d2e6c23b-2060x1366.jpeg?itok=bk_SdoJ3" alt="">
```

How can I remove this markup. Can I use views-view-field-field_name.tpl.php. Only line this file contains is print $output. How can i use this file to remove markup. Or does any preprocess hook helps

Comment: Are you using the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module? Then your answer may be here: [Customize Rendered File markup?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106177/customize-rendered-file-markup)

Comment: Yes I am using File Entity module

Answer (score 0):

You can use theme layer to override the views output , if you want only theme a certain field you can use this template file :`views-view-field.tpl.php`

for more information check this tutorial : [Theming a single field in a Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2331589)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews) module, it is good module that can help you get rid of unwanted Drupal wrappers.

Here are some more details about this module(quotes from its page):

> This Views plugin makes unformatted styles, field row styles and other
>   output more readily configurable without needing to override template
>   files. Instead of overriding row style templates for views where you
>   want to specify different HTML elements (tags) and class attributes,
>   you can specify these inside the Views UI and avoid overriding
>   templates for each view.
>
> Some of Semantics Views functionality can be done in Views, but Views
>   is restricted to use only predefined HTML element and can only style
>   each Field but not wrap rows with any HTML you like.